# Azure Data Explorer Query Language-batches and materialize

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/materializefunction
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/batches

I am using Microsoft's demo portal: https://aka.ms/LADemo

> A query can include multiple tabular expression statements, as long as
>   they are delimited by a semicolon (;) character. The query then
>   returns multiple tabular results, as produced by the tabular
>   expression statements, and ordered according to the order of the
>   statements in the query text.

When I run following code I am only getting result from the first expression and not the second and third one. Which is contrary to the above statement. Why?

```
let randomSet = materialize(range x from 1 to 30000000 step 1 | project value = rand(10000000));
randomSet | summarize dcount(value);
randomSet | top 3 by value;
randomSet | summarize sum(value)
```

Picture of the result set:
[image]

Comment: How are you running your query? i.e. which client application or client library are you using? The more information you include, the better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log Analytics does not support this feature, to try it out use the Kusto (Azure Data Explorer) [demo cluster](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples), you will see multiple tables in the output pane:
[image]